# Insert user role with user id and role id in abp permission table

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

In Asp.net Boilerplate I am looking for a method to insert permission of a user with user id and role id. I check some reference but still did not find a way to achieve it.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```
var role = await _roleManager.GetRoleByIdAsync(roleId);
await _roleManager.SetGrantedPermissionsAsync(role, permissions);
```

This will grant the persiossions to the role

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, [UserManager<TUser>.AddToRoleAsync(TUser, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.addtoroleasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2) adds to a role by its name.

In ASP.NET Boilerplate, you can get the `role` by its `int` `roleId` and then pass on the `role.Name`.

```cs
public async Task<IdentityResult> AddToRoleAsync(long userId, int roleId)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);
    var role = await _roleManager.GetRoleByIdAsync(roleId);

    return await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
}
```

Related: [What is the difference between Roles and Permissions in ASP.NET Boilerplate Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56998725/8601760)

Comment: will it insert the permission into abppermissions table?

Comment: No. Do you want user role, user permission or role permission?

Comment: It does not make sense to add permission for a user role.

Comment: I want to add role wise user permissions in abppermission table i.e I have a common user which will have different role access, so here on the basis of the selected role, I want to show specific page access.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.