# Can I use the AbpAuthorize attribute with roles and not permissions?

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate, user-roles

I thought that in the Asp. Net Boilerplate, I would do the authorization not by permissions, but by roles. Is it possible?

Comment: No, authorization only depends on permissions, not roles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Roles and Permissions in ASP.NET Boilerplate Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56998725/what-is-the-difference-between-roles-and-permissions-in-asp-net-boilerplate-temp)

Comment: Thank you, it looks like I can solve the problem with this.